# import sql database from chembl fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to import a mysql database from this source: https://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/chembl/ChEMBLdb/latest/ , specifically the chembl_31_mysql.tar.gz file which containts one .dmp file and some instructions file. I downloaded on my pc and followed their instructions but I did not manage to completed successfully. In the final step the cursor just flashing indefinitely as showed in the screen photo. I have never worked with mysql (only with mongodb) and I do not know what I am doing wrong.[image]

Comment: Are you sure you unzipped the folder correctly? Your path contains a .tar folder.

Comment: yes. chembl_31_mysql.tar this is just a folder name